# React: confused result when deleting one of the components with the same key and the same props

Tags: reactjs

I am learning how React keys work. And I using an array with a list of objects to generate lists of React elements in which there are two elements with the same key and the same props. When I delete the first element by clicking the delete button, there are tree elements on the screen(2, 2, 2) and the expecting result is two(2, 2). It confused me. 
Does anyone knows the reason of this confused result? There is a [demo link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/restless-sea-r0i9c).

```
const COMPONENT_LIST = [
  { key: 1, value: 1, id: 1 },
  { key: 2, value: 2, id: 2 },
  { key: 2, value: 2, id: 3 }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    arr: COMPONENT_LIST
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({
              arr: COMPONENT_LIST
            });
          }}
        >
          Recover
        </button>
        <ul>
          {this.state.arr.map(item => (
            <li key={item.key}>
              {item.value}
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  this.setState({
                    arr: this.state.arr.filter(ele => item.id !== ele.id)
                  });
                }}
              >
                Delete
              </button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

keys must be unique for each element

```
const COMPONENT_LIST = [
  { key: 1, value: 1, id: 1 },
  { key: 2, value: 2, id: 2 },
  { key: 3, value: 2, id: 3 }
];
```

[React Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)